# There is something wrong VS There must be something wrong

Tags: phrase-usage

Do the selected phrases mean the same and are they completely interchangeable?

> **There is something wrong in** you code.
>
> **There must be something wrong with** your code.

Answer (score 1):

In normal everyday usage, these two phrases are not interchangeable. "There is something wrong in your code" is a statement of fact. "There must be something wrong with your code" is an accusation which may or may not be correct. The latter does not even require that there is a problem in the first place.